# React-Formik dropdown errors on selection

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am getting the converting circular structure error on selecting an item from the client dropdown.

using this code to create the dropdown. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
    const FormSelect = ({ name, options }) => {
    const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name);

    console.log(options);
    return (
      <>
        <FormControl.Select
          size="lg"
          name={name}
          value={field.value}
          onChange={(v) => helpers.setValue(v)}
          >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.key} value={option.key}>
              {option.value}
            </option>
          ))}
        </FormControl.Select>
      </>
    );
  };
```

return (

```
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    InvoiceNumber: '',
    InvoiceDate: Date.parse('1985-10-20'),
    ClientId: '',
    CompanyId: '',
    PaymentStatusId: '',
    PaymentTerms: '',
    Total: '',
    Notes: '',
    InvoiceDetails: [{
      Id: '',
      Description: '',
      Quantity: '',
      Amount: '',
      VatPercentage: '',
      VatAmount: '',
      Total: ''
    }]
  }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    InvoiceNumber: Yup.string().required(),
    InvoiceDate: Yup.string().required(),
    ClientId: Yup.string().required()
  })
  }
  onSubmit={(values) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(values));
  }}
>



  {/* {({ errors, touched,props }) => ( */}
  {props => (
    <Container>
      <Form>


<Row>
              <FormControl.Label column="lg" lg={2}>
                Client
              </FormControl.Label>
              <Col>
       

                <FormSelect name="ClientId" options={clientItems.map((client) => ({ "value": client.Value, "key": client.Key }))} />

             
                <span className="text-danger">
                  {props.errors.ClientId && props.touched.ClientId ? (
                    <div>{props.errors.ClientId}</div>
                  ) : null}
                </span>
              </Col>
</Row>

.....
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So changed the select control to this

```
const FormSelect = ({ name, options }) => {
    const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(name);
    const formikProps = useFormikContext()
    return (
      <>
        <FormControl.Select
          size="lg"
          name={name}
          {...field}
          onChange={(e) => { 
            formikProps.setFieldValue(name, e.target.value);
          } }
          onBlur={() => helpers.setTouched(true)}
          >
          {options.map((option) => (
            <option key={option.key} value={option.key}>
              {option.value}
            </option>
          ))}
        </FormControl.Select>
        <span className="text-danger">
          {meta.error && meta.touched ? (
            <div>{meta.error}</div>
          ) : null}
        </span>
      </>
    );
  };
```